# How to auto save data every month?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

`CentreInvoice` model:

```py
class CentreInvoice(core_models.TimestampedModel):
    centre = models.ForeignKey(Centre, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="c_centre_invoice")
    rcl_share_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    total_billed_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    paneluser = models.ForeignKey("panel.PanelUser", related_name="c_invoice_creator", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    total_advance_payment = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I am using this model to generate invoices in my project. I need to save this manually everytime, but I want it to happen automatically every month. Is there a way to do this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: make a task in taskmanager (Windows) or cron (Linux) that executes the code every month

Comment: Hi @SembeiNorimaki Thankyou for the suggestion. I am working on Linux. So I think Cron will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely achieve it using Celery + Celery Beat + Redis

- **Celery**: it will be used for the background task
- **Celery Beat**: Celery beat is a scheduler
- **Redis**: it will be used as a celery broker, you can use any broker such as rabbitmq, etc.

Another option will be:

1. Create a custom command on your Django app
2. Create a cron job and call this custom command using this cron job.

I prefer the first approach because I can manage all my schedulers at the code level.

PS: I am working on the Django starter-kit which will have all these basic features, it will be an open-source Django app :)

Comment: Hi @Zilay ! Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely implement one of these. And if you can post your projects links. I would like to see.

Comment: Sure, I will share it. Right now, I am working on it.